# php get mp3 file duration remote file

Tags: php, id3

I trying to get `mp3` file's duration via `ID3` from `remote file`, from `url` but it returns `0` any solution?

```
$getID3 = new getID3;
$file = $getID3->analyze($srv . $path . $filename);
$playtime_seconds = $file['playtime_seconds'];
$duration = gmdate("i:s", $playtime_seconds);
echo $duration;
```

Comment: Have you verified that your path and filenames are right, and $file actually contains something?

Comment: @Astinox yes, i get file size via `$head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($srv . $path . $filename, TRUE));
$size = $head['content-length'];` it works fine.

Comment: I was talking about if `$file` in your code has an object?

Comment: @Astinox `$file` is a `string` like this: `$file = 'test.mp3';`

Comment: If `$file` is a string, you're trying to get an array parameter from a string, which is obviously not working. Make sure that `$file` is the actual MP3 file analyzed you want

Answer (score 0):

I get answer as **"Remote files are not supported - please copy the file locally first"**. So there is no way without downloading the file.